# Pixel points between cubes

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am working on an app but I encountered a problem, if I place multiple cubes one over the other, somethimes small white pixel appears.

Does anyone know how to get rid of them? The cubes are the same size.

[image]

You need to pay attention to see them on this picture, but are very visible on phone.

Comment: You should get a screen shot from the phone and upload it. Even put it in a red circle. I can't see the white pixels here

Comment: I think he meant these spots [http://imgur.com/zTNHLnF](http://imgur.com/zTNHLnF)

Comment: That's the level of artifact? Screw it, publish. No one will notice or care.

Comment: Yes. Those spots. Isn't there a way to get rid of them?

Comment: Unity has some problems with antialiasing combined with shadows. Maybe this is the cause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed the problems are occurring around the boundaries of objects.

I'm suspecting the glitch could be from "the z-depth issue", or the near-far clipping problem.

Did you intend to make the y-values of two objects for Top/Bottom Cubes equal?

```
topCube.bottomY = 2;    // transform.position - height/2
bottomCube.upY = 2;     // transform.position + height/2
```

If this is the case try to make the cubes far enough from each other. Set the y values to be 2.001 and 1.999 instead of 2 and 2.

Also, try to get another test devices or even on other platforms and see if the same thing happens over there.

Comment: I was adding the exact same values on X and Z, I was only modifying the Y axis by adding +1. Note that the cubes had the height = 1. But I managed to hide those bleeding by adding -0.0001 on X axis every time I added a new cube.

As you said, I changed the X values by summing the initial position with a -0.0001. Althought, it's not what I wanted, it fixed my problem.

Comment: I know it's not pretty but I'm afraid it will be the only option to avoid the issue. If you find the 0.001s are noticable in games, you could make it even smaller. As long as it is greater than `the minimum precision points accuracy` it will do the work.

Answer (score 0):

The real question is: *how* do you put these cubes on top of each other?

To me, those spots don't look "white", they seem to be the color of the top of the cubes, bleeding through seams between the cubes. Such seams appear if you stack polygons onto each other that don't share the exact same vertices. The rendering of adjacent triangle edges is only guaranteed to be seamless if they share the *exact same* start and end coordinates..

That means that if you put two cubes on top of each other, but shift one of them 0.0001 units in any direction, seams might appear. It also means that if you want to put a small cube on top of a large cube, seams might appear.

Comment: I was adding the exact same values on X and Z, I was only modifying the Y axis by adding +1. Note that the cubes had the height = 1. But I managed to hide those bleeding by adding -0.0001 on X axis every time I added a new cube.